# Sort content on page Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component and table.
I get an object from the server and display it in the table. I want to add sort buttons that change the information displayed in the table by type.
This is my table-components:

```js
<app-home-modal-button></app-home-modal-button>
<app-home-button></app-home-button>
<div class="searchBox">
  <input type="text" class="searchBoarder"/>
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</div>

<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-nav">
        <th scope="col">שנה</th>
        <th scope="col">סוג הדוח</th>
        <th scope="col">ח.פ</th>
        <th scope="col">שם החברה</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let tax of currentPage">
        <tr>
          <td>{{tax.year}}</td>
          <td>{{tax.type}}</td>
          <td>{{tax.cid}}</td>
          <td>{{tax.company}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="table-footer">
  <pagination class="pagination" nextText=">" previousText="<"  [totalItems]="totalItems" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"> </pagination>
</div>
</div>
```

components ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanyService } from '../../../../core/services/company.service';
import { Tax } from 'src/app/entity/tax.entity'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-taxreports',
  templateUrl: './taxreports.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./taxreports.component.sass']
})
export class TaxreportsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private service: CompanyService) {
  }

  taxList: Tax[];
  totalItems: Number;
  currentPage: Tax[];
  page: Number = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getTaxList().subscribe(data => {
      this.taxList = data;
      this.totalItems = data.length;
      this.currentPage = data.slice(0, 10)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  pageChanged(event) {
    const startItem = (event.page - 1) * event.itemsPerPage;
    const endItem = event.page * event.itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = this.taxList.slice(startItem, endItem);
  }

}
```

The problem is that i dont want to sort All the length of the object.
I want the sorting done only on the information shown in the table, because the information is divided into several pages using pagination.

Comment: For me, when you sort a paginated table, you do want to filter all results not only the showed ones...

Comment: ok, how i filter all result?